# filter JSON by two different values

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using a function to filter a JSON file based on the value of the year key, like so:

```
function filterYr(json, key, value) {
  var result = [];
  for (var year in json) {
    if (json[year][key] === value) {
      result.push(json[year]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

I'm then setting a default:

```
var chooseYear = filterYr(json, 'year', "2000");
```

However there's also a dropdown, so the JSON file can be filtered onchange of the dropdown select option.

**My question** is, can I use this same function to filter the same JSON file by another value, too?

So for instance, I also want to filter by the key 'type.'
If it were a new function it'd be:

```
function filterType(json, key, value) {
  var result = [];
  for (var type in json) {
    if (json[type][key] === value) {
      result.push(json[type]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

But how do I combine that into one function?
And then how do I set a default that passes both the 'type' and the 'year' to the function?
Is that possible?

Thank you and let me know if I can provide more detail if this isn't clear.

PS- I'd prefer to just use javascript and not a library, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data structure is like below, your current function just works well

```
var items = [
  {
      year: 2000,
      type: 'type1'
  },
  {
      year: 2001,
      type: 'type2'
  }
];

function filterYr(json, key, value) {
  var result = [];
  for (var year in json) {
    if (json[year][key] === value) {
        result.push(json[year]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

filterYr(items, 'type', 'type2'); //[ { year: 2001, type: 'type2' } ]
filterYr(items, 'year', 2000); //[ { year: 2000, type: 'type1' } ]
```

You just need to use a more general name for your function and year variable

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the function so it accepts an object as criterion for filtering. The following function accepts an object with n number of properties:

```
function findWhere(collection, props) {
    var keys = Object.keys(props), // get the object's keys 
        klen = keys.length; // cache the length of returned array

    return collection.filter(function(el) {
        // compare the length of the matching properties
        // against the length of the passed parameters
        // if both are equal, return true
        return keys.filter(function(key) {
            return el[key] === props[key];
        }).length === klen;
    })
}

var filteredCollection = findWhere(arrayOfObjects, { 
   type: 'foo', 
   anotherProp: 'aValue' 
});
```